# Selector in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So I couldn't find exactly this question in the last 15 mins of searching - although maybe I missed it somewhere - and is it seems a fairly obvious question feel free to point me in the right direction and don't flame me too hard :)

I'm building my first jQuery plugin - which is for a really simple accordion. Now I want in my particular case to initialise this plugin for a particular accordion instance. But what I haven't really understood is when I search for the onClick events in my plugin how to be sure they correspond only to the selector.

So at a basic level if I do

```
$("#someAccordion").accordion();
```

with associated html

```
<div id="someAccordion"
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="header active">Title</div>
        <div class="content>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="header inactive">Title 2</div>
        <div class="content>
            <p>Some different text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without the accordion plugin normally you'd have a trigger like the below:

```
$('#someAccordion .header').click(function () {
```

But with the accordion I'd like to assume I'm already in that `#someAccordion` element. But how can I tell that I'm in that accordion instance and not some other one that's on my page?

Comment: Where is your attempt at writing the plugin?

Comment: With jQuery plugins, you'll have the containing element, so when you bind your click events, you should be able to bind only to the events that happen within that element.  Seeing what you've tried (as @Roamer-1888 suggests) would help us to figure out how to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/JoomJunk/Accordion/blob/e363eaf6cb59fa26f0e720fd032e1cc9b8d9ae92/mod_accordion/media/js/jjaccordion.js This is my plugin. What I have is a variety of elements. What I want to do is call each plugin instance (with different params) for each ```#accordion' + options.id``` instance. But I dunno if I need to keep that same code inside the plugin instance :/

Comment: Had a quick look at your plugin code. Having a DOM ready event inside that code does not make sense. You need to hook up your event handlers inside the constructor/init method of the plugin instead, and listen for the desired event *relative to the element the plugin is connected to*. Take a look at the model provide by jQuery UI Widget to create plugins.

Comment: Yeah that's what comes of writing code at 3am :) Indeed the dom ready should be around where i call the plugin rather than inside the plugin.  https://github.com/JoomJunk/Accordion/blob/plugin/mod_accordion/media/js/jjaccordion.js

Comment: By the init you're talking about making a plugin in the manner suggested by the first boilerplate code here? (as obviously in the real world I don't want to be jQuery UI dependent) http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/

Comment: Not seen that specific one before, but yes. Like that.

Comment: OK so using this jQuery boilerplate code I found on more research https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js. And what I'm not clear about is how to get the vars in my .on('click') event. The best I can do is pass them with the event. But then I'd really want the event to be private. And I don't see how to make a private method in this plugin system :/

Comment: Moved this rehash into a different file now btw https://github.com/JoomJunk/Accordion/blob/plugin/mod_accordion/media/js/jjaccordion2.js feel free to subject your worst to it. Best way to learn :)